# The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, chat, flutter-futurebuilder

I am trying to build an app that contains chat, but the error message appears because this line:

```
 return FutureBuilder(
      future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser,
```

- 

```
The argument type 'User' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<dynamic>'.
```

my code
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjbIr.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`currentUser` is a property and it returns a value of type `User` therefore you don't have to assign it to the `future` property, just do:

```
User user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

Comment: but what should I write in "future:" ,,,, FutureBuilder(future: ....)

Comment: Nothing don't use FutureBuilder since currentUser is synchronous immediately gives result